# SQL server min and MAX date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with below data

[image]

i want the output as

[image]

EMP 25FC0938-88EE has 3 entries. The ID against the oldest date should be entered in column A and rest in Column B.

How can i achieve this in SQL

Comment: case ... when ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `first_value()` :

```
select firstvalue as columnA, id as columnB
from (select *, first_value(id) over (partition by us order by date) as firstvalue
      from table
     ) t
where id <> firstvalue;
```

*If* you want to insert the result-set of the preceding query then use `INSERT . . INTO` statement

```
insert into table (columnA, columnB)
select firstvalue as columnA, id as columnB
from (select *, first_value(id) over (partition by us order by date) as firstvalue
      from table
     ) t
where id <> firstvalue;
```

Comment: The output table is already created. I need to insert the values base on the above criteria